# why do I get the segmentation fault in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying do write a program for gaussian elimination with pivoting and I cant seem to input any values into my matrix. The code compiles but after I enter the matrix a and the vector b i get the segmentation fault (core dumped) error message. I dont know why I get that. Any ideas?

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n;

    std::cout << "Enter dimension \n";        
    std::cin >> n;     

double** a = new double*[n];
double** A = new double*[n];
double* u = new double[n];
double* b = new double[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a[i] = new double[n];
    A[i] = new double[n+1];
}

std::cout << "Enter the elements of the matrix row-wise:\n";
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        std::cin >> a[i][j];
    }    
}


std::cout << "Enter b " << "\n";
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    std::cin >> b[i]; 
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
         A[i][j] = a[i][j];
    } 

}


for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
{
    A[j][n] = b[j];
}



for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int k = i+1; k < n; k++)
    {
         if (A[i][i]<A[k][i])
         {
             for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
             {
                double temp=A[i][j];
                A[i][j] = A[k][j];
                A[k][j] = temp;
             }
         }

    }

}                    

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int k = i+1; k < n; k++)
    {
        double t = ((double)(A[k][i]))/((double)(A[i][i]));
        for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        {
            A[k][j] = A[k][j] - t*A[i][j]; 
        }

    }

}            


for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)                
{                        
    u[i] = A[i][n];                
    for(int j = i+1; j< n; j++)
    {
         if (j != i)
         {
             u[i] = u[i]-A[i][j]*u[j];
         }

    }

    u[i] = u[i]/A[i][i];           
}

std::cout << "Solution" << "\n";

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     std::cout << u[i] << "\n";  
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. It will help you with situations like this. SO is *not* a debugger.

Comment: Why all the pointers? Why are there no explanatory comments in your code so that readers can see why it does what it does? Why do your variables have non-descriptive, single-character names? Why is your code not properly indented? Why have you not used a debugger to investigate your problem?

Comment: `j <= n` looks yucky.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: in fairness to the OP, regarding variable names they might be following a similar convention to me: that being in mathematical code, symbols used in a supporting mathematics paper overrule any other variable naming conventions. (E.g. G for Newton's constant, `c` for the speed of light in a vacuum etc.)

Comment: I think you're learning why functions are so useful.  No one wants to try and understand what a god function does.  In the mean time, here's an article you should read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Bathsheba: At the very least, that should be explained by documenting comments in the source file.

Comment: The first obvious problem is the loop `for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {A[j][n] = b[j];}`.  `A` and `b` are both allocated with `n` elements, so this loop falls off the end of both.   This gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over indexing one of your arrays.

Change the code

```
for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
{
    A[j][n] = b[j];
}
```

To

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    A[j][n] = b[j];
}
```

Comment: Is one of the problems, yes.